# Box-Shadow cut off in Safari

Tags: css

I'm having issues with box-shadows being cut off in Safari, but fine in Chrome. I've tried "overflow: visible", but that isn't working. See link below.

```css
li {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  height: 140px;
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
  /* thought this should work  */
  padding: 0;
  border: no;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: rgba(45, 45, 45, 0.1) 0px 2px 4px, rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.04) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.1) 0px 8px 10px, rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.04) 0px 16px 18px, rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.1) 0px 32px 32px, rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.1) 0px 64px 64px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <button type="button">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/any">
   </button>
</li>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/stevenmlamb/pen/zpmVeN)

Thanks!

Comment: try   -webkit-box-shadow for safari

Comment: No luck. I updated the codepen, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't really understanding why overflow: visible isn't working. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: The solution I found was to the give the parent of the element with the shadow some padding.

Comment: same problem here with drop-shadow

Comment: same problem here, using a transparent outline at the moment, I don't want to though since that will catch touch events there where I don't want it to.

Answer (score -1):

instead of the button tag, use the div tag works like charm.

```html
<li>
  <div>
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/any">
  </div>
</li>
```